# How to use pivot function to transfer these rows to columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Went to MSDN and back, yet am still confused as ever on how to use the pivot function.  How I transform the following code to transfer the rows to columns?

```
SELECT
 YEAR(hiredate) AS Year, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM 
 Faculty
GROUP BY 
 YEAR(hiredate)
```

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM Faculty
PIVOT
(
  Count(*)
  FOR Year(Hiredate) IN(....)
) as p;`

Comment: It is saying `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '*'.` with that code.  Replaced the ellipsis with '1999','2000','2001','2003'...etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT  pvt.[2010], pvt.[2011], pvt.[2012], pvt.[2013], pvt.[2014]
FROM    (   SELECT  [Year] = DATEPART(YEAR, HireDate), V = 1
            FROM    Faculty
        ) AS f
        PIVOT
        (   COUNT(V)
            FOR [Year] IN ([2010], [2011], [2012], [2013], [2014])
        ) AS pvt;
```

`PIVOT` does not allow you to use a function on the column to pivoted (e.g. `YEAR(HireDate)`), nor does it allow `COUNT(*)` so you need to put the function into a subquery, and also create a column to use to count (`V` in this example).